# 'Book.Book.title' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, visual-studio, message

This is the code for my Books Class

```
public Book(String title, String author)
{
    {
        this.title = title; 
        author = "Anon";
    }
}

public String Title
{
    get
    {
        return title;
    }
}

public String Author
{
    get
    {
        return author;
    }
}
```

This is my Program for it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Book> newBookList = new List<Book>();
        newBookList.Add(new Book("Cake shop", "michael purgo"));
        foreach(Book boo in newBookList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Book name is" + boo.title);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I am trying to add a list of book objects but I keep getting a message saying 'Book.Book.title' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to access the field `title` which is `private`, you should use `Title` property, which is `public`.

```
Console.WriteLine("The Book name is" + boo.Title);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added + boo.Author to the console.writeline and it comes up with the boo.Title but not  boo.Author. Any Suggestions?

Comment: In constructor you set the `author = "Anon"` this will not set the class author. you must set it : `this.author = author;`

Comment: Please edit your post, and add the new problem as well

Answer (score 3):

`title` is private field of `Book`, you need to access `Title` which is public and actually returns `title`.

Try this,

```
public class Book
{  
     private string title;
     private string author;
     public Book(String title, String author)
     {       
          this.title = title; 
          this.author = author;        
     }
     public String Title
     {
         get
         {
              return title;
         }
     }

     public String Author
     {
          get
          {
               return author;
          }
     }
}
```

now in main method

```
List<Book> newBookList = new List<Book>();
newBookList.Add(new Book("Cake shop", "michael purgo"));
foreach(Book boo in newBookList)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Book name is" + boo.Title + " and author is " + boo.Author);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added + boo.Author to the console.writeline and it comes up with the boo.Title but not  boo.Author. Any Suggestions?